# Why use separate jobs and stages on a single GitLab runner?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab pipeline config and **a single** GitLab runner. There are currently 3 stages in the pipeline:

1. install_dependencies
2. lint
3. test

There is no deployment stage.

The stages for installing dependencies and testing have both 1 job in them. However, the lint stage has 5 linters: ESLint, Prettier, tsc (the TypeScript compiler for type checking), cspell (for spell checking) and jscpd for code duplication checking. The issue is that each of the jobs, although running in parallel, has an overhead of provisioning a Docker container, fetching the git repository, downloading and uploading cache and installing Node packages from cache.

The stage for installing dependencies only runs `npm ci` by making use of a cached `.npm` directory.

The test job in the test stage runs Jest.

All of the tasks take **little time and can be run in less than 2 minutes** even sequentially.

I am curious if there are any benefits of such a pipeline setup except the easy overview of the pipeline progress that the GitLab UI provides? Why would I need multiple stages and jobs if there are no dependencies between jobs and stages in my case and everything may just go under one single job in one single stage?

Comment: In this case I'd actually run all 5 linters in a single job and accumulated return codes of each linter, then fail or warn the job should any linter report fail/warning, or however you handle linter errors.

Answer (score 1):

One word: parallelism. Especially if there are no dependencies between jobs, the whole pipeline finishes a lot quicker if several of these jobs can run in parallel.

At least that's the idea. Node.js and its millions of small .js files are really hard on Gitlab performance, so in that case you might effectively skip out on that aspect.

You can try having separate `package.json` files and caches that only install specific linter packages for these jobs.

Comment: I agree. But I believe that in my case this only increases the pipeline build time by a large extent because of the provisioning time needed. The task themselves are really fast, they take no more than 2 minutes if run sequentially so there is no added benefit of the parallelism that GitLab jobs provide.

That's what led me to the question whether there are any benefits except the overview in the UI in my case?

Comment: That might indeed be a problem of that specific setup then. Another thing you could do, maybe as your project grows, is to group jobs by type and for example have one job for linting, one job for unit tests, one for end-to-end tests etc. That way there might be a balance between setup overhead and overall performance gain.